# WCF in Windows Mobile 6.5

Tags: wcf, windows-mobile-6.5

currently when I run WCF services in Windows Mobile 6.5, it shows the errors of

```
System.Net.WebException was unhandled
  Message="WebException"
  StackTrace:
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.doInvoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters, WebClientAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
       at SmartDeviceProject1.localhosttesting.SKHService.AddNumber(Double n1, Boolean n1Specified, Double n2, Boolean n2Specified, Double& AddNumberResult, Boolean& AddNumberResultSpecified)
       at SmartDeviceProject1.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
       at Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterMainLoop(IntPtr hwnMain)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form fm)
       at SmartDeviceProject1.Program.Main()
```

Anyone knows how to solve it? Currently if I use Windows form to connect, I can use the WCF but if I use the emulator or device, it throws this exception.

Answer (score 0):

I have searched for a whlie to this issue and found unrelated results. I found that there can be more than one reason to see this message.

To find out your problem, first add this line to your WCF configuration file and then focus on the given detailed exception.

```
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
```